# sssd-pac.service crashes periodically on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sssd

We are using the RedHat IdM 7 and have bound our server systems for central user management to our IdM cluster. We have recognized on our Ubuntu 20.04 systems that the `sssd-pac.service` crashes periodically every 7-8 minutes and gets automatically restarted. Unfortunately, we have not found the reason so far. We are running the following SSSD version:

```
(~) root@srv2-t $ sssd --version
2.2.3
```

The `/var/log/syslog` contains the following entries:

```
Oct  7 11:01:32 srv2-t  sssd_pac[537014]: dbus[537014]: The last reference on a connection was dropped without closing the connection. This is a bug in an application. See dbus_connection_unref() documentation for details.
Oct  7 11:01:32 srv2-t  sssd_pac[537014]: Most likely, the application called unref() too many times and removed a reference belonging to libdbus, since this is a shared connection.
Oct  7 11:01:32 srv2-t  sssd_pac[537014]:   D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
Oct  7 11:01:32 srv2-t  systemd[1]: sssd-pac.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Oct  7 11:01:32 srv2-t  systemd[1]: sssd-pac.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Oct  7 11:01:32 srv2-t  systemd[1]: sssd-pac.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct  7 11:01:32 srv2-t  systemd[1]: Stopped SSSD PAC Service responder.
Oct  7 11:01:32 srv2-t  systemd[1]: Starting SSSD PAC Service responder...
Oct  7 11:01:32 srv2-t  systemd[1]: Started SSSD PAC Service responder.
Oct  7 11:01:33 srv2-t  sssd_pac[537271]: Starting up
Oct  7 11:09:03 srv2-t  sssd_pac[537271]: dbus[537271]: The last reference on a connection was dropped without closing the connection. This is a bug in an application. See dbus_connection_unref() documentation for details.
Oct  7 11:09:03 srv2-t  sssd_pac[537271]: Most likely, the application called unref() too many times and removed a reference belonging to libdbus, since this is a shared connection.
Oct  7 11:09:03 srv2-t  sssd_pac[537271]:   D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
Oct  7 11:09:03 srv2-t  systemd[1]: sssd-pac.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Oct  7 11:09:03 srv2-t  systemd[1]: sssd-pac.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Oct  7 11:09:03 srv2-t  systemd[1]: sssd-pac.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.
Oct  7 11:09:03 srv2-t  systemd[1]: Stopped SSSD PAC Service responder.
Oct  7 11:09:03 srv2-t  systemd[1]: Starting SSSD PAC Service responder...
Oct  7 11:09:03 srv2-t  systemd[1]: Started SSSD PAC Service responder.
Oct  7 11:09:03 srv2-t  sssd_pac[537522]: Starting up
```

All other depend services are socket activated and the `sssd.conf` has no `services` entry for services that should directly run on startup:

```
[domain/lx.mycompany]
id_provider = ipa
ipa_server = _srv_, idm2.lx.mycompany
ipa_domain = lx.mycompany
ipa_hostname = srv2-t.lx.mycompany
auth_provider = ipa
chpass_provider = ipa
access_provider = ipa
cache_credentials = True
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/ipa/ca.crt
dyndns_update = True
dyndns_iface = ens160
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash

[sssd]
domains = lx.mycompany

[nss]
homedir_substring = /home

[pam]
offline_credentials_expiration = 7

[sudo]

[autofs]

[ssh]

[ifp]

[secrets]

[session_recording]
```

We have recognized that there are two `sssd_pac` processes running, one gets started directly with the `sssd.service` and the other one gets activated by `sssd-pac.socket`. The socket activated process periodically crashes after 7-8 minutes, while the other one runs without any issue.

Let’s restart SSSD and check the process list:

```
(~) root@srv2-t  $ systemctl stop sssd* --all
(~) root@srv2-t  $ systemctl start sssd.service
(~) root@srv2-t  $ systemctl status sssd.service
● sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-10-07 12:31:04 CEST; 9s ago
   Main PID: 540692 (sssd)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 9448)
     Memory: 8.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/sssd.service
             ├─540692 /usr/sbin/sssd -i --logger=files
             ├─540705 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_be --domain lx.mycompany --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
             └─540706 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pac --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files

Oct 07 12:31:03 srv2-t  systemd[1]: Starting System Security Services Daemon...
Oct 07 12:31:04 srv2-t  sssd[540692]: Starting up
Oct 07 12:31:04 srv2-t  sssd_be[540705]: Starting up
Oct 07 12:31:04 srv2-t  sssd_pac[540706]: Starting up
Oct 07 12:31:04 srv2-t  systemd[1]: Started System Security Services Daemon.
Oct 07 12:31:04 srv2-t  sssd_be[540705]: GSSAPI client step 1
Oct 07 12:31:04 srv2-t  sssd_be[540705]: GSSAPI client step 1
Oct 07 12:31:04 srv2-t  sssd_be[540705]: GSSAPI client step 1
Oct 07 12:31:04 srv2-t  sssd_be[540705]: GSSAPI client step 2
(~) root@srv2-t  $ ps aux | grep sssd_
root      540705  0.1  0.2  71752 19740 ?        S    12:31   0:00 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_be --domain lx.mycompany --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
root      540706  0.0  0.1  38836 13932 ?        S    12:31   0:00 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pac --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
root      540751  0.0  0.0   6300   736 pts/0    S+   12:31   0:00 grep --color=auto sssd_
```

After a user has logging in into the system. We get the following:

```
(~) root@srv2-t  $ ps aux | grep sssd_
root      540705  0.1  0.2  72168 21720 ?        S    12:31   0:00 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_be --domain lx.mycompany --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
root      540706  0.0  0.1  38836 13932 ?        S    12:31   0:00 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pac --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
root      540752  0.1  0.4  58416 39016 ?        Ss   12:31   0:00 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_nss --logger=files --socket-activated
root      540787  0.0  0.1  33436 13308 ?        Ss   12:32   0:00 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_ssh --logger=files --socket-activated
root      540806  0.0  0.1  33980 13448 ?        Ss   12:32   0:00 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pam --logger=files --socket-activated
root      540810  0.0  0.1  38968 14664 ?        Ss   12:32   0:00 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pac --logger=files --socket-activated
root      540921  0.0  0.0   6300   736 pts/0    R+   12:32   0:00 grep --color=auto sssd_
```

After round about 15 minutes the socket activated `sssd_pac` processs got restarted twice. Have a loot at the reported startup time.

```
(~) root@nxrepo-srv2-t $ ps aux | grep sssd_
root      540705  0.0  0.2  72164 20944 ?        S    12:31   0:00 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_be --domain lx.eurodata.de --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
root      540706  0.0  0.1  38836 13932 ?        S    12:31   0:00 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pac --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
root      541428  0.0  0.1  38836 13960 ?        Ss   12:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pac --logger=files --socket-activated
root      541546  0.0  0.0   6432   736 pts/0    S+   12:51   0:00 grep --color=auto sssd_
```

This is the log entry:

```
Oct  7 12:32:18 srv2-t sssd_pac[540810]: Starting up
Oct  7 12:32:19 srv2-t kernel: [8020600.723391] audit: type=1400 audit(1633602739.238:35): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd" name="/etc/selinux/semanage.conf" pid=540811 comm="selinux_child" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Oct  7 12:39:13 srv2-t sssd_nss[540752]: Shutting down
Oct  7 12:39:13 srv2-t systemd[1]: sssd-nss.service: Succeeded.
Oct  7 12:39:46 srv2-t sssd_ssh[540787]: Shutting down
Oct  7 12:39:46 srv2-t systemd[1]: sssd-ssh.service: Succeeded.
Oct  7 12:39:48 srv2-t sssd_pam[540806]: Shutting down
Oct  7 12:39:48 srv2-t systemd[1]: sssd-pam.service: Succeeded.
Oct  7 12:39:48 srv2-t sssd_pac[540810]: dbus[540810]: The last reference on a connection was dropped without closing the connection. This is a bug in an application. See dbus_connection_unref() documentation for details.
Oct  7 12:39:48 srv2-t sssd_pac[540810]: Most likely, the application called unref() too many times and removed a reference belonging to libdbus, since this is a shared connection.
Oct  7 12:39:48 srv2-t sssd_pac[540810]:   D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
Oct  7 12:39:49 srv2-t systemd[1]: sssd-pac.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Oct  7 12:39:49 srv2-t systemd[1]: sssd-pac.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Oct  7 12:39:49 srv2-t systemd[1]: sssd-pac.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Oct  7 12:39:49 srv2-t systemd[1]: Stopped SSSD PAC Service responder.
Oct  7 12:39:49 srv2-t systemd[1]: Starting SSSD PAC Service responder...
Oct  7 12:39:49 srv2-t systemd[1]: Started SSSD PAC Service responder.
Oct  7 12:39:49 srv2-t sssd_pac[541181]: Starting up
Oct  7 12:47:19 srv2-t sssd_pac[541181]: dbus[541181]: The last reference on a connection was dropped without closing the connection. This is a bug in an application. See dbus_connection_unref() documentation for details.
Oct  7 12:47:19 srv2-t sssd_pac[541181]: Most likely, the application called unref() too many times and removed a reference belonging to libdbus, since this is a shared connection.
Oct  7 12:47:19 srv2-t sssd_pac[541181]:   D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
Oct  7 12:47:19 srv2-t systemd[1]: sssd-pac.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Oct  7 12:47:19 srv2-t systemd[1]: sssd-pac.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Oct  7 12:47:19 srv2-t systemd[1]: sssd-pac.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Oct  7 12:47:19 srv2-t systemd[1]: Stopped SSSD PAC Service responder.
Oct  7 12:47:19 srv2-t systemd[1]: Starting SSSD PAC Service responder...
Oct  7 12:47:19 srv2-t systemd[1]: Started SSSD PAC Service responder.
Oct  7 12:47:20 srv2-t sssd_pac[541428]: Starting up
```

How can we get rid of the problem?

Thanks a lot.